# Java how to convert cmyk raw image data to jpeg?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagemagick

I have **uncompressed image data in CMYK color space in java byte array**.
How can i create a jpeg image from this byte array?

Comment: 1) Create a `BufferedImage` from the CMYK data. 2) `ImageIO.write(..the JPG..)`